# Alerts on metrics that are no longer reported

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have an alert based on a metric reported by node-exporter - to report whenever a node is down for more than 2 mins. We run node-exporter as a DaemonSet in a kubernetes cluster.

The problem is sometimes the nodes are removed permanently and we continue to get alerts.  I am wondering what is correct way to resolve these alerts in an automatic manner.

If the "FOR" clause allows a range, say FOR 2m upto 24h, then that could work for me but I dont know if that is supported.

For reference here's the rule we have -

```
ALERT InstanceDown
  IF up{job="kubernetes-node-exporter"} == 0
  FOR 2m
  LABELS { 
    severity = "page"
   }
  ANNOTATIONS {
    summary = "Node {{ $labels.instance }} is down",
    description = "Node {{ $labels.instance }} of job {{ $labels.job }} has been down for more than 2 minutes.",
  }
```

PS: In the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prometheus-developers/iP2k68eUVrM Brian Brazil says the following. Does it apply to node-exporter too which needs to run on every node?

> We consider the one exporter per machine to be an anti-pattern, as
>   it's a bottleneck both technically and operationally as well as
>   increasing the impact of a failure of one exporter.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like staleness in Prometheus 1.x, a higher FOR clause such as 10m will handle that.

> Does it apply to node-exporter too which needs to run on every node?

Only one exporter per machine that does everything is an anti-pattern. Running the node exporter everywhere is the expected way to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I do want one alert though, just not repeatedly. I assume with 10m I will get one alert when the target stops reporting?